# Can someone explain what maxBit is?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, 64-bit

I am trying to understand what is maxBit in the following and what it represents?

When I print min and max, I get numbers that make no sense to me.

Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
union {double a; size_t b;} u; 
u.a = 12345; 
size_t max = u.b; 
u.a = 6; 
size_t min = u.b;
int maxBit = floor(log(max-min) / log(2));
printf("%d",maxBit);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: writing to one member of a union and reading from another is almost always undefined behavior.

Comment: Also, how much of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format have you memorized?

Comment: Also, how big are `size_t` and `double` on your compiler?

Comment: It's tagged `[64-bit]` so he is fine on the size of the types. I'm not sure what meaning the quotent of the natural log of the difference in the unsigned representations of the floating-point values and 2 will provide?

Comment: 64 bits. I think we can replace size_t by uint64_t. Does that help?

Comment: It looks like a wonky way to find the MSB?? Above the output is `55`, but if you set `-12345` you get `63` reflecting the sign-bit being set. (still not sure of the precise purpose)

Comment: Maybe. Can you explain what is MSB? What is MSB used for? Thank you. How would you find the MSB in a non wonky way ? :-)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: log(a)/log(b) is the base-b logarithm of a, regardless of the base of the log function.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, please post all your comments below and I will accept it as the right answer. If you have a better way of doing it, please suggest an alternative so I can learn good practice. Thank you.

Comment: Where did this code come from?

Comment: MSB means most significant bit. When talking about a field, say a 16-bit integer type with bits labeled 15 to 0, the most significant bit is the one with the highest position value, so, in this example, bit 15, with position value 2^15 = 32768. When talking about a specific number, say 11, the most significant bit is the highest one set in its binary representation. With 11, its binary representation is 1011, so its most significant bit is bit 3, with position value 2^3 = 8.

Comment: The C standard does not provide any non-wonky way to find the most significant bit of a value; it has no operator or function for it. The choices are: (a) Write a loop to test the bits to find the greatest value bit that is set, which can be done in standard C but nominally is a waste of computing. (b) Use a compiler extension like GCC’s __builtin_clz. (c) Use floating-point logarithms, which is wasteful and runs into portability issues and may fail for wide integers (e.g., 64-bit integers with 64-bit float, the latter of which have 53-bit significands). (d) Method (a) with some bit twiddling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code appears to be using a horrible kludge. I am one of the more welcoming participants here regarding tolerating code that uses compiler extensions or other things beyond the C standard, but this code does simply unnecessary things for no apparent good purpose. It relies on `size_t` being 64 bits. It may be 64 bits in some specific C implementation this was written for, but that is not portable, and  C implementations that use 64 bits are generally modern, and modern implementations ought to support the `uint64_t` of `<stdint.h>`, which would be an appropriate type for this. So better code would have used `uint64_t`.

Unless there is some quite surprising motivation for this and other issues in the code, it is low quality, bad code. Do not use it, and regard any code from the same source with skepticism.

That said, the code likely assumes the IEEE-754 binary64 is used for `double`, and `max-min` gives the difference between the representations of 12345 and 6. `log(max-min) / log(2)` finds the base-two-logarithm of `max-min`, and the integer portion of that will be the index of the highest bit that changed. For 12345, the exponent field is 1036. For 6, the exponent field is 1025. The difference is 11 (binary 1011), in which the first set bit is bit 3 of the exponent field. The field runs from bits 62 to 52 in the binary64 format, so bit 3 in the exponent field is bit 55 (52+3) in the whole 64 bits of the representation. So maxBit will be 55. However, there is no apparent significance to this. There is no great value in knowing that bit 55 is the highest bit set in the difference between the representations of 12345 and 6. I am familiar with a variety of IEEE-754 bit-twiddling hacks, and I do not recognize this. I expect nobody can tell you much more about this without context, such as where the code came from or how it is used.

Comment: Sorry I am probably not at the same level as the others. Would you be able to explain how you get the values 140 and 129, as well as the 3 and 62 and 52? Thank you.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil For 64 bit (double precision) (for value 12345) : exponent is `1023+13 = 1036`, but for 32bit (single precision) : exponent is `127 + 13` =140.

Comment: @Suresh_Patel: Did you encounter this same code somewhere? Where?

Comment: @KrishnaKanthYenumula, thanks for the link. I understand the 1036 and 1025, would you be able to explain the 3 (2^3 = 8) please?

Comment: @momo123: 11 = 8+2+1, so, in binary, it is 1011. The first bit there is bit 3, representing 2^3 = 8.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, yes I did encounter very similar code but I did not understand what it does. Would you be able to explain me the logic behind it? I am happy to open a new topic. Please look at lines 158 to 167 of https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/src/fsort.c

Answer (score 2):

From [C17 document](https://web.archive.org/web/20181230041359if_/http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf), 6.5.2.3  Structure and union members, footnote 97 :

> If the member used to read the contents of a union object is not the
> same as the member last used to store a value in the object, the
> appropriate part of the object representation of the value is
> reinterpreted as an object representation in the new type as described
> in 6.2.6 (a process sometimes called “type punning”). This might be a
> trap representation.

Therefore, when you store `u.a = 12345` and then access `size_t max = u.b`, the bit patterns in the memory of `u.a` is reinterpreted as a `size_t`. Since, `u.a` is of double, it is represented in IEEE754 format.

The value stored in `max` and `min` are :

4668012349850910720 (0100000011001000000111001000000000000000000000000000000000000000-> IEEE754)
4618441417868443648 (0100000000011000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000-> IEEE754)

Then, `max-min = 49570931982467072`, then `log(max-min)/log(2) = 55.460344`, then  `floor(55.460344) = 55`. This is reason for 55 as output.

PS: There are two types of IEEE754 format : Single precision (32) and Double precision (64). Please visit this website [IEEE754](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ieee-standard-754-floating-point-numbers/) for more details.